# TouchableOpacity is not working properly with navigation

Tags: react-native, expo

I put TouchableOpacity for onPress because View can not make it. When i gave TouchableOpacity onPress with navigation it stopped working. Why is not working? Help me please.
Code:

```html
<TouchableOpacity style={{flex:2}}
                activeOpacity={.7}
                onPress={() => navigate('Articles', {
                  otherParam: rowData.article_title
                })}>
             <Image
        source = {{ uri: rowData.mobile_image }}
               style={{resizeMode:'cover',width:null,height:null, flex:1,  borderRadius:4,
                 borderWidth:1,
                 borderColor:'#dddddd'}}
             />

             <Text
             style={styles.textOfArticle}
             >
               {rowData.article_title}
             </Text>

  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: were you get `navigate` in onPress . ?

Comment: @Hardik Virani from variable

Comment: Can you show us the whole content of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `TouchableOpacity` must have only one child component. You are adding `Image` and `Text` components separately. They must be wrapped in a `View`.

Change it like this,

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flex:2}}
                activeOpacity={.7}
                onPress={() => navigate('Articles', {
                  otherParam: rowData.article_title
                })}>
             <View>
             <Image
        source = {{ uri: rowData.mobile_image }}
               style={{resizeMode:'cover',width:null,height:null, flex:1,  borderRadius:4,
                 borderWidth:1,
                 borderColor:'#dddddd'}}
             />

             <Text
             style={styles.textOfArticle}
             >
               {rowData.article_title}
             </Text>
             </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```